# error in accessing action view of the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting this error "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Vidly.Models.Movie' because 'Vidly.Models.Movie' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' " on this line "@foreach (var movie in Model)"

My movies controller is this

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public MoviesController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        // GET: Movies
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var movie = _context.Movies.Include(m => m.Genre).ToList();
            return View(movie);
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var movie = _context.Movies.Include(m => m.Genre).SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
            if (movie == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
            return View(movie);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Index action View implementation

```
@model Vidly.Models.Movie
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Movies</h2>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Movie</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var movie in Model)    // getting error on this line
        {
            <tr>
                <td> @Html.ActionLink(@movie.Name, "Details", "Movies", new { id = movie.Id}) </td>
                <td>@movie.Genre.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have also implemented another action view implementation for another controller very similar to this one but that didn't cause any error ...

Comment: In this case movie is the model type, not a list of movies so you cant run a foreach on a movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model declaration on the view is wrong, it should be:

```
@model IEnumerable<Vidly.Models.Movie>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you've defined the model in your view as a single movie.  Your model needs to be an enumerable type

```
@model IEnumerable<Vidly.Models.Movie>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Movies</h2>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Movie</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var movie in Model)    // getting error on this line
        {
            <tr>
                <td> @Html.ActionLink(@movie.Name, "Details", "Movies", new { id = movie.Id}) </td>
                <td>@movie.Genre.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```